# Concrete 5 summary detail page

Tags: content-management-system, master-detail, concrete5

The solution is probably not unique to Concrete5 CMS, but I need to build a page with a list of items. Each item would link to a detail page of that item showing a full text description.
Each item on the initial summary page would have the first few lines of the detail page description and a "more" link.
Does anyone know how I could go about doing this in C5?

Comment: 'page description and a <more> link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common thing to do with Concrete5, and there is a built-in block to handle it -- it's called "Page List".
Note that out-of-the-box, this block doesn't show the first few lines of each page's content, but rather shows the "description" field as entered when creating the page (or editing the page's properties). But I have a free addon available in the marketplace called "Page List Teasers" -- http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/page-list-teasers -- which adds this functionality to the built-in Page List block.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out the blog views of the page list - they show how to display an area from another page with all the content blocks they contain, and how to display attributes.  You could make a rich text attribute called description then display that as you loop through the list of pages.